# Opening Hyperlinks in Excel VBA issue

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I've been trying to find/write a macro that opens all hyperlinks contained in a selected range at once. The code I've come across works on only some types of hyperlinks, specifically hyperlinks added through either the right click/Insert>Link/Ctrl+K. The code wont recognise any hyperlinks that are formed using the HYPERLINK() function.

Here's the code I found online:

```
Sub OpenMultipleLinks()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set myRange = Application.Selection
    Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Range", "OpenMultipleLinks", myRange.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each oneLink In myRange.Hyperlinks
        oneLink.Follow
    Next
End Sub
```

And here's the formula of a cell that becomes a hyperlink.

```
=IF($D2="All Charts","",HYPERLINK("http://SubstituteWebsite/ChartId="&$D2&$AF$1,"link"))
```

Comment: The `Hyperlinks` collection contain only inserted hyperlinks. The other one is a `Formula`. The `HYPERLINK` part of the formula can act only in special circumstances. In your case, only if `$D2="All Charts"`. Would you like to follow hyperlinks even if this condition is not fulfilled? Would you like to evaluate the whole formula and follow the hyperlink only if the condition is true? If yes, this is should be possible only if we can assume that the formula you show us is a general pattern to be applied to all formulae. So, what do you need, from this point of view?

Comment: So, do all your formulae respect the pattern you posted? I mean, the link string is build from concatenation of a root with two concatenated cells value...

Comment: All of my selected cells will follow this scructure, the $D2 cell is a chart ID's and the $AF$1 cell is the second half of the text string to create a valid link. The formula is meant to return a blank if the chartID is instead "All Charts", because data from certain charts are combined in the same place as the data is stored. I think excel is creating a hyperlink in both situations strangely, because I can't add a hyperlink to these 'blank' cells.   What I'd like is a macro that opens all of these links for me.

Comment: Then, did you test the solution I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not answer my clarification questions, I will assume that my understanding is correct. So, the following code will work if your formulae containing 'HYPERLINK' formula inside respect the pattern you show us and it should be followed without evaluating if the formula condition is `True`:

```
Sub OpenMultipleLinks()
    Dim myrange As Range, cel As Range, oneLink
    On Error Resume Next
     Set myrange = Application.Selection
     Set myrange = Application.InputBox("Range", "OpenMultipleLinks", myrange.Address, Type:=8)
     For Each oneLink In myrange.Hyperlinks
          oneLink.Follow
     Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    For Each cel In myrange
        If InStr(cel.Formula, "HYPERLINK") > 0 Then
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink extractHypFromFormula(ActiveCell.Formula)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function extractHypFromFormula(strForm As String) As String
    Dim Hpos As Long, startP As Long, Hlength As Long, strRoot As String
    Dim startP2 As Long, cellsAddr As String
    Hpos = InStr(strForm, "HYPERLINK") 'it returns position of the first character for "HYPERLINK" string in the formula
    If Hpos > 0 Then
         startP = Hpos + Len("HYPERLINK") + 2 'it builds the position after which to start searching
                                                               '+ 2 because of '(' and "
         Hlength = InStr(startP, strForm, """") - startP 'length of the hyperlink fix part (before the strings taken from the two cells value)
         strRoot = Mid(strForm, startP, Hlength) 'it returns the hyperlink fix part
         startP2 = startP + Len(strRoot) + 2      'next START to return the string keeping the concatenation of the two cells value
         cellsAddr = Mid(strForm, startP2, InStr(startP2, strForm, ",") - startP2) 'the string keeping the concatenation of the two cells value
         'split the string on "&" separator and use the two elements as range string:
         extractHypFromFormula = strRoot & Range(Split(cellsAddr, "&")(0)).value & Range(Split(cellsAddr, "&")(1)).value
    End If
End Function
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it...

Comment: This works well, thank you! Do you know how I would make them all open in a new window together?

Comment: @Elis Theoretically, yes. Practically, I never could see it opening a new window. It maybe behaved in this way only in Internet Explorer. Just a supposition... If you want trying it is simple. Create a new variable `Dim count As Long` then put `count = count + 1` like first line of the iteration. `If count = 1 Then ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=extractHypFromFormula(ActiveCell.Formula), NewWindow:=True`. But, like I said, it should work but it does  not. Ask Microsoft, why...

Comment: I understand that the line `Hlength = InStr(startP, strForm, """") - startP` finds the length of the string part of the hyperlink (http://SubstituteWebsite/ChartId= in my code example), how does the `""""` part achieve this? I think that `"""" ` gives a string equal to "", but then within my formula text string there's never a case of 2 "", only one? it was my understanding that InStr takes inputs `InStr({position in string to start searching from}, {string to search in},{string expression being searched for})`.

Comment: Now I am driving... when I will be at home, I willcomment the code.

Comment: @Elis `inStr` function behaves a little different than you think. Its first parameter is `Optional`. I mean, if VBA find it like a `Long` variable it considers `start` parameters. If it is a string, VBA skips 'start' and considers it as 'string to be searched`. Now, """" means only ". In VBA "" means an empty string, """ das  not have a meaning itself, it can be used only at the beginning or at the end of the string to mean ". In the above code it searches the next ". Now, I will try commenting all the code lines which may be not so clear...

Comment: @Elis Commented the function lines in a way to understand what each of them does.

Comment: Very clear, thanks for your detailed help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse/evaluate the "hyperlink" formula first. Assuming all your links are in col A this will do what you want:

```
    Sub link()
        Dim arr, arr2, j As Long
        arr = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Formula2 'get all in an array
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If Left(arr(j, 1), 3) = "=HY" Then 'check if it's a formula
                arr(j, 1) = Evaluate(Split(Mid(arr(j, 1), 2), ",")(0) & ")") 'split the url from the rest, evaluate and replace in array
            End If
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=arr(j, 1), NewWindow:=True 'open in default browser
        Next j
    End Sub
```

Best of luck,

ceci